# ¿como hacer promedio en cmd (visual studio)?

Tags: c#

Tengo este programa, que es para sacar el promedio de "X" cantidad de números, no entiendo que es lo que estoy haciendo, porque no sale el promedio, estoy seguro que el problema está en las operaciones que están en el `for`.

```
        double _numero = 0;
        double _promedio = 0;
        double _contador = 0;

        Console.Clear();

        Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de números que quiere promediar: ");
        _contador = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < _contador; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese los números: ");
            _numero = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            _promedio = _numero + _numero / _contador;

        }
            Console.Write($"\nEl promedio es: {_promedio}")

        Console.Write("\n\nPulse Enter para salir...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error está en que estás tomando la variable equivocada a la hora de hacer la suma del cálculo del promedio.

La línea:

```
        _promedio = _numero + _numero / _contador;
```

debe ser en realidad:

```
        _promedio = _promedio + _numero / _contador;
```

El código completo, sería:

```
    double _numero = 0;
    double _promedio = 0;
    double _contador = 0;

    Console.Clear();

    Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de números que quiere promediar: ");
    _contador = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < _contador; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese los números: ");
        _numero = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        _promedio = _promedio + _numero / _contador;

    }
        Console.Write($"\nEl promedio es: {_promedio}")

    Console.Write("\n\nPulse Enter para salir...");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas calcular el promedio fuera del `for` asi:

```
double _numero = 0;
    double _promedio = 0;
    double _contador = 0;

    Console.Clear();

    Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de números que quiere promediar: ");
    _contador = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < _contador; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese los números: ");
        _numero += double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            

    }
    _promedio = _numero / _contador;
        Console.Write($"\nEl promedio es: {_promedio}")

    Console.Write("\n\nPulse Enter para salir...");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar el programa, por ejemplo si le doy que _contador = 3 al ingresar 10,20,30 el resultado debería ser 20 pero da igual a 10.

Comment: Copiaste y pegaste mi codigo?  Nota que la variable `_numero` usa el operador `+=` en lugar de `=`.

Comment: sale error de compilación con tu código, pero ya me respondieron que la operación iba dentro del `for` como  `_promedio = _promedio + _numero / _contador`